# How to improve my Angular Ng-repeat and stop freezing the page?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I'm using angular to display my attendance register application. I needed to render a table with teams and it's associated users along with attendance data.
I used ng-repeat to render the table using following code but the table freezes when I tried to apply any filters or even when I tried to load it normally. Please help.

Laravel Blade View

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-show="!loading">
                <table class="table table-bordered text-center" ng-repeat="team in teamsAndAttendances | filter: { 'id': teamFilter }:true track by $index">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="active text-center" colspan="100%">@{{ team.name }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center info">Day</th>
                        <th class="text-center" ng-repeat="weekDay in weekDays track by $index" ng-class="getDayStringClass(weekDay)">@{{ weekDay | amDateFormat: 'ddd' }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center info">Date/Engineer</th>
                        <th class="text-center active" ng-repeat="weekDay in weekDays track by $index">@{{ weekDay | amDateFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in team.users">
                        <th class="text-center active">@{{ user.name }}</th>
                        <td 
                            ng-repeat="day in getNumberOfDays(weekDays.length) track by $index"
                            ng-bind="getAttendanceByDate(weekDays[$index],user.id)"
                            id="attData" 
                        ></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Angular Controller

```
function AttendanceCtrl($scope,LeavesAndAttendancesFactory,moment,$resource) {

var vm = $scope;

vm.plClass = false;

vm.loading = false;

vm.teamsAndAttendances = [];

vm.attendanceObject = {};

LeavesAndAttendancesFactory.getTeamsUsersAttendances().query().$promise.then(function(res) {
    return vm.teamsAndAttendances = res;
});

vm.getNumberOfDays = function(days) {
    return new Array(days);
}

vm.getAttendanceByDate = function(dateStamp,userID) {

    var fetchedDate = moment(dateStamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    var users = angular.forEach(vm.teamsAndAttendances, function(team) {
        return team.users;
    });

    console.log(users);
}

vm.getAttendanceClass = function(plClass) {
    if(plClass)
    {
        return 'danger';
    } else {
        return 'active';
    }
}

vm.loadTeams = function() {
    return $resource('../api/teams/all').query().$promise.then(function(data) {
        vm.teams = data;
    });
}

vm.getDayStringClass = function(dateStamp) {
    var day = moment(dateStamp).format('ddd');
    if(day === 'Sat' || day === 'Sun')
    {
        return 'light-fire';
    } else {
        return 'info';
    }
}

var today = moment();

vm.weekDays = [];

var startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week');
var endOfWeek = moment().endOf('week');

var day = startOfWeek;

while (day <= endOfWeek) {
    vm.weekDays.push(day.toDate());
    day = day.clone().add(1, 'd');
}
```

}

Comment: You are building your data on the fly in the template. Moving all this to the controller should speed up things. I recommend you prepare all the data in the controller and let the template only display the data without all the function calls like getAttendanceByDate etc

Comment: @osi Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm at a little lost here.

Comment: Do the same as in your template but instead of writing the logic in your template use for loops in your controller.

Comment: @osi Thanks a lot. Will try it now.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `filters` with `ng-repeat`.
Ng-repeat with filter will affect the page performance as mentioned in the document.

Try filtering data in controller or service itself and ng-repeat with the already filtered data.

And use `ng-bind` instead of `{{ }}`.

For example :

```
app.controller("controllerName", function(){
    $scope.allData = [1,2,3,4];
    $scope.filteredData = [];

    $scope.filterData(){
        var data = [];
        data = _.filter($scope.allData, function(a){
            if(a > 3){
                return a;
            }       
        });

        $scope.filteredData = data;
    }

    $scope.filterData();
});


<div ng-repeat = "item in filteredData" >
    <span ng-bind="item"></span>
</div>
```

Defiantly this approach will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try fast-repeat plugin. https://github.com/gradecam/angular-fast-repeat. Also you can try one time binding: https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/